# What does this ominous "System.Drawing" warning mean?

Tags: asp.net, imaging

I am in the process of developing some image-processing code for an ASP.NET web site that will eventually be exposed as a web service.

At the bottom of the System.Drawing namespace docs:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx

is this ominous warning:

```
Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use 
within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from 
within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such 
as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported 
alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.
```

By "ASP.NET service" do they mean web service? I don't think "Windows Imaging Components" are designed to do what I'm doing with images.

Is the System.Drawing namespace safe for image processing within an ASP.NET web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement means any ASP.NET applications, including WebForms, MVC, Web API and SignalR.

System.Drawing was only designed for WinForms or console applications that run in a normal user session.

Somebody else might claim that System.Drawing works for them in those not-supported scenarios, but simply that's not supported by Microsoft at all.

Comment: Holy cow, I had absolutely _no idea_. We've got some System.Drawing-based code that generates thumbnails for uploaded images we've been using for years. I may need to revisit that...

Comment: @n8wrl then you are just so lucky. Some hardware/software might just run it happily, but a suitable library for server scenarios is being discussed on corefx repo at GitHub. There might be something good coming in this area.

Comment: Looks like CoreFX might be a ways off. Can you recommend a server-side-capable library?

Comment: @n8wrl https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2020#issuecomment-159993316 Discussions like this show none is suitable yet and new things might come some time.